# Hapi js client side caching

Tags: caching, hapi.js

Could someone post an example of how to implement client side caching with Hapi js? I am new in learning Hapi and would like to see some basic example of client side caching implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
server.route({
    path: '/hapi/{ttl?}',
    method: 'GET',
    handler: function (request, h) {

        const response = h.response({ be: 'hapi' });

        if (request.params.ttl) {
            response.ttl(request.params.ttl);
        }

        return response;
    },
    options: {
        cache: {
            expiresIn: 30 * 1000,
            privacy: 'private'
        }
    }
});
```

Follow this link for more info: https://github.com/outmoded/hapijs.com/blob/master/lib/tutorials/en_US/caching.md